# How to click accept button after taking photo in selenium

Tags: android, python, selenium, adb

I have used

```
self.driver.keyevent(27)
```

to capture an image in Python with `selenium`. However, the screen that I get is as shown below.

Basically I need to click the accept button (with red border) so that the image capture is complete. I know, that I can use in adb shell,

```
input tap 1000 1500
```

and it works great. But how do I achieve the same using the Python script?

[image]

Even just a way to execute this via the selenium script would be OK for me

```
input tap 1000 1500
```

Something like self.driver.execute("adb shell input tap 1000 1500");

Answer (score 1):

In Python, it is uncommon to click on an element by its coordinates, can you please try looking for this accept buttons's Xpath or Css selector expression?

For Android testing, you may consider using [this tool](http://selendroid.io/)

Below is a Python code snippet about how to click on a pair coordinates, as you can see, you need to use an element as reference.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox() //Or whichever browser you prefer
driver.get("your url")
reference=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("Your xpath here")

action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(reference, X, Y)
action.click()
action.perform()
```

Since you need to locate an element as reference anyway, why not simply click on this element directly without using coordinates?

Comment: Thanks. The only issue is that, that is a camera app of the android phone is opened at the moment, so we are not in a web context any more. So i have managed to capture a  photo already. But i have to accept the image for the image to be returned to the app that opened the camera. The code that i need therefore is for clicking the accept image button on the camera app.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["adb", "shell", "input keyevent 27"]) # capture
subprocess.call(["adb", "shell", "input tap 1000 1500"]) # accept the captured image
```